# Addressing memory in a simulator

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management, 32-bit, memory-address

Writing a simple 32-bit simulator (in C++) but managing the memory is throwing me into a loop.

My plan was to have a 2D array, the first being pointers each pointing to blocks of memory which are created on first read/write into the block.

The issue I am having is how to address it properly, if I need, for example, 2<sup>16</sup> bit addresses for memory does that mean that.

- I need 2048 words worth of memory (where each word is a 32-bit `uint`)
- Which could be split into 64 blocks of 32 words (each block being 1024 bytes, or 8192 bits)

I am under the impression this would appear something like as follows

```
    uint32_t* m[64];
    // When first read or write into a block create as follows
    m[block] = new uint32_t[32];
```

This would mean the last accessible address would be 0xfffc (as 0x10000 is the total amount of addresses).

Now, if this is all correct (which I am not certain it is) I think actually getting to the memory would be as follows

```
    uint32_t whichBlock = addr / (32 * 4);
    uint32_t blockLoc = (addr % 32) / 4;
```

This seems to work for, say for example 0x80 as the address as `whichBlock` would be 1 and `blockLoc` would be 0 (i.e. the 1st word in the 2nd block) but is obviously wrong when the address is something like 0xff8c which gives `whichBlock` as 511 and `blockLoc` as 3.

Obviously I have gone completely wrong with my calculations somewhere, but I can't figure out where!

Comment: If you only need 2^16 bits of memory, just create a vector (or array, if you must) of the right size, and be done with it. The amount of memory involved is *far* too small to be worth the trouble (and implementing it may use enough code that it ends up costing more than it saves).

Comment: sorry, I guess I should have made this clear but I actually have to address 2^32 bits of memory, which is far too big for a vector. I simply stated 2^16 because i was trying to work with smaller values for easy understanding, thankyou

Comment: 2^32 bits still isn't too big for a vector. It does provide a *little* more justification, but I'd still just use a vector at least for a first cut (and work at reducing memory usage later, when/if measurement showed it was a significant factor--but it probably won't).

Comment: Silly me for having read specifications wrong, I appreciate the feedback because reading your answers made me realize I have fundamentally misunderstood the specifications. What I was looking for was that address themselves are 32 bits (or 16 bits in my example) meaning that the array would be too big to just have as a single array. I have edited the original question to reflect this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have some rows, each of which contains 32 `uint32_t`s .

That means that if `n` is the index of the `uint32_t` (from 0 to 2047) then the row is `n / 32` and the column is `n % 32`.

You didn't say how you are mapping your addresses but I assume you mean that addresses `0` through `3` are the first `uint32_t` and so on . If so, then divide the address by `sizeof(uint32_t)` to get `n` in my previous paragraph.

So you could have:

```
size_t address = 0x1234;
size_t index = address / sizeof(uint32_t);
size_t whichBlock = index / 32;
size_t blockLoc = index % 32;
```

Comment: much appreciated @Matt I think I really was just overthinking and frying my brain